# How to create a virus isolating environment to run children games

Tags: windows-7, linux, virtualbox, centos, virus

- I have a Linux Centos 6 server in the garage without a monitor or keyboard, and it does not hold any sensitive information.
- My wife has a Windows 7 laptop which she surfs the Internet, checks emails, uses MS Word, and pays bills online.
- My 10 year old Daughter wants to play Minecraft on the laptop, spent the past 2 weeks earning money to buy the base program, and now needs to download various executable programs.

I am a little nervous about my wife surfing the Internet on the same Machine that she pays bills, but I am very nervous about my Daughter running executables, so I told her last night she couldn't play Minecraft on the laptop, and she burst off in tears.

Without buying a new PC, what options do I have to be reasonably safe? I am thinking of creating a virtual box on the Linux server, install Windows and Minecraft on it, and somehow letting access that platform via the laptop and play her game.  Is this possible, will it contain most viruses, and if so how?  Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Minecraft is a virus-free game, so your daughter can safely install and play it on laptop. You don't need to worry about that.

Anyways, there is also a java runnable file for Minecraft, too. You can try installing JRE first, and then run the `.jar` file. This way your daughter won't run executables!

Comment: Evidently, there are plugins or modules you can download to fly on a dragon or something similar.  How do I know she is going to the right site to download them?

Comment: if you want your daughter to download plugins/modules from a specific site, you can use a parental control software to prevent access to any website except that specific site.

Comment: @user1032531 just forbid her from going to those sites.

Comment: @Ramhound.  How do I know which sites?  They look innocent enough, but I do not have the time to research each to that level.  If I take this stance, I need to forbid her from going to any site.

Comment: Not looking for ways to restrict access or parenting styles but how to create such an isolated environment.  Think better to post this question in serverfault?

Comment: Virtual Box gives you the isolated environment you want, but you can't use your laptop monitor and keyboard on your Linux server. You may install Virtual Box on the laptop.

Comment: @Pazis.  But can one remote desktop into it or something similar?

Comment: Yes. You can connect to it remotely, but it wouldn't give your daughter a very smooth experience. I mean the game would react after some delay based on the network.

Comment: Moreover, VMs, by definition cannot use the actual graphics hardware. It's being used by the host so the guest cant use it too. I mean VMs are not designed for gaming! You can get better performance by installing the directx additions though.

Comment: Network is hardwired CAT5.  I know that VirtualBox Remote Display Protocol (VRDP) is available and and might render quicker than MS RDP. Don't know whether it will be "quick enough".  Where would directx be installed?

Comment: DirectX should be installed on virtual machine (Windows).

Comment: while the official minecraft is virus-free, there are plenty of scams that pretend to be tools or replacement clients. not all are bad, but it's important to be ware when downloading anything that's not the official client